# Get / Read laravel 5.8 Storage non public Folder files to View?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-storage

> Try to access 'storage/app/folder1/a.png' from my view

[image]

```
public function viewStorageFiles()
{
    $fileFullPath = Storage::disk('local')->path('folder1/a.png');
    $fileUrl = Storage::disk('local')->url('app/folder1/a.png');
    $storage_path = storage_path('app/folder1/a.png');

    return view('email.fileDownload')->with([
        'fileFullPath' => $fileFullPath,
        'fileUrl' => $fileUrl,
        'storage_path' => $storage_path,
        ]);
}
```

> In view : email.fileDownload

```
<div>
    <p>  asset($fileUrl) ==> {{asset($fileUrl)}}</p>
    <img src="{{asset($fileUrl)}}"/>
</div>
<div>
    <p>  url($fileUrl) ==> {{url($fileUrl)}}</p>
    <img src="{{url($fileUrl)}}"/>
</div>
<div>
    <p>  storage_path($fileUrl) ==> {{storage_path($fileUrl)}}</p>
    <img src="{{storage_path($fileUrl)}}"/>
</div>
```

the result is : [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There could be many answers to this!

You could `create a symbolic link from "public/storage" to "storage/app/public"` using the following command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Above command will map your `storage/app/public` directory to `public` directory.

Now let's consider you have `user1.jpg` and `user2.jpg` files in your `storage/app/public` directory, you can access them in the following way:

```
http://your-domain.com/storage/user1.jpg
http://your-domain.com/storage/user2.jpg
```

*** Updated my answer based on your comment: ***

You can return a file response from a route that is protected by some middleware!

For example - following route returns file response from `storage/app/uploads` directory that is not accessible publicly:

```php
Route::get('storage/{file}', function ($file) {
    $path = storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
    return response()->file($path);
});
```

You could secure above route in anyway and use it in your views..

I hope that helped..

Comment: Thank you. but i have already done this php artisan storage:link; and the result still the same . this command just to make public storage folder accessible ; the issue how to access non-public folder content through view .

Comment: @EskanderOne - Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for this

Answer (score 0):

Go to config/filesystems add this array

```
'public_site' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('storage'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ]
```

then your function could be like this

```
public function viewStorageFiles()
{
    $fileFullPath = Storage::disk('public_site')->path('folder1/a.png');
    $fileUrl = Storage::disk('public_site')->url('app/folder1/a.png');
    $public_path = public_path('storage/app/folder1/a.png');

    return view('email.fileDownload')->with([
        'fileFullPath' => $fileFullPath,
        'fileUrl' => $fileUrl,
        'storage_path' => $public_path,
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Could you pls explain what happend here ? why I have to change the config file ?

Comment: You don't have to change the config file, you have to add an array to the config. You are creating a configuration for a public storage folder.
Config files are modificable, vendor files no