# How to display file in laravel-8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I can upload file in database [image]
and it is stored in my upload files.

[image]
Now I want to display it in in my `show.blade.php`, so I did this, but it is not working.

```
<iframe src="/storage/uploads/{{ $file->file_path }}"  width="400" height="400"></iframe>
```

as result I got this not found in show.blade.php
[image]

So how can I display it? This is my `FileController.php`

```
class FileUpload extends Controller
{
  public function createForm(){
    return view('file-upload');
  }

  public function fileUpload(Request $req){
        $req->validate([
        'file' => 'required'
        ]);

        $fileModel = new File;

        if($req->file()) {
            $fileName = time().'_'.$req->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $filePath = $req->file('file')->storeAs('uploads', $fileName, 'public');

            $fileModel->name = time().'_'.$req->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileModel->file_path = '/storage/' . $filePath;
            $fileModel->save();

            return back()
            ->with('success','File has been uploaded.')
            ->with('file', $fileName);
        }
   }

   public function show(File $file)
    {
        // $news=News::find($id);
        return view('show',compact('file'));
    }

}
```

this is `web.php`

```
Route::get('/upload-file', [FileUpload::class, 'createForm']);

Route::post('/upload-file', [FileUpload::class, 'fileUpload'])->name('fileUpload');
Route::get('/uploadshow', [FileUpload::class, 'show']);
```

Thanks

Screen short of ifream
[image]

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is `storage` a folder, or even a symlink, in your webroot?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view help?

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479687/get-read-laravel-5-8-storage-non-public-folder-files-to-view

Comment: Judging from the screenshot: did you try to remove the `=` at the beginning of the `src` attribute? That looks pretty wrong to me

Answer (score 0):

You need to put proper path in `iframe` using `asset()`

```
<iframe src="{{ asset('storage/app/public/uploads/') }}/{{ $file->file_path }}"  width="400" height="400"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks but not working still file not found

Comment: Can you check using f12 what path exactly iframe is taking? please add screenshot of that also

Comment: please check update

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. For example, why is there a `=` at the beginning of the `src` attribute?

Comment: your $file variable is not fetching data from database can you show us using `dd($file)`

Comment: @NicoHaase it was a typo. thank you for indicating

Comment: @ShahedKhan please remove `=` from the beginning of src. it was a typo by me

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

You may use the URL method to get the URL for a given file. If you are using the local driver, this will typically just prepend /storage to the given path and return a relative URL to the file. If you are using the s3 driver, the fully qualified remote URL will be returned:

```
 <iframe src="{{ URL::asset('storage/uploads/'.$file->file_path}}"width="400" height="400"></iframe>
```

Comment: still not found

Answer (score -1):

Your route uploadshow should have parameter fileId like this uploadshow/{fileId}.

Then in your show function will be show($fileID).
$file = File:find($fileID)

In your frame src,
asset($file->file_path)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).